# How to get the product of two properties from a list of objects in Java 8

Tags: java, list, java-stream, bigdecimal

I have a list of objects with price and quantity. And I am looking to get the total sum, which is the sum of all (product price * product qty) in the list of objects. What's the best way to do this is in Java 8?

I could get the sum of all product prices by streaming list with `list..stream().map(Product::getPrice).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add));` but what I am not sure is how to get the product of price and quantity as well.

Comment: Please provide a full, working simplified example of your code

Comment: 1: create method `getTotal` returning the product (price * qty) and use it in above code; or 2: use `p -> p.getPrice().multiply(p.getQty())` instead of `Product::getPrice`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calculate the product using `map` and then get the sum with `reduce`:

```java
list.stream()
    .map(p -> p.getPrice().multiply(p.getQty()))
    .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```